# How should the general type of a "lemma" function be understood?

Tags: haskell, theorem-proving, dependent-type, higher-rank-types

Perhaps this is a stupid question. Here's a quote from [the *Hasochism* paper](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf):

> One approach to resolving this issue is to encode lemmas, given by
>   parameterised equations, as Haskell functions. In general, such lemmas
>   may be encoded as functions of type:
>
> ```
> ∀ x1 ... xn. Natty x1 → ... → Natty xn → ((l ~ r) ⇒ t) → t
> ```

I thought I understood `RankNTypes`, but I can't make sense of the last part of this proposition. I'm reading it informally as "given a term which requires `l ~ r`, return that term". I'm sure this interpretation is wrong because it seems to lead to a circularity: we don't know `l ~ r` until the conclusion of the proof itself, so how can I be expected to provide as an assumption of the proof a term which requires that?

I would have expected an equality proof to have a type more like this:

```
Natty x1 → ... → Natty xn → l :~: r
```

Informally, "given a bunch of `Natty`s, return a proof of the proposition that `l` and `r` are equal" (using GHC's [Data.Type.Equality](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html)). This makes far more sense to me, and seems to align with what you'd say in other dependently typed systems. I'm guessing it's equivalent to the version in the paper, but I'm struggling to mentally square away the two versions.

In short, I'm confused. I feel like I'm missing a key insight. How should I read the type `((l ~ r) => t) -> t`?

Comment: Someone light the @pigworker signal.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I think you have to project a `Π` onto the night sky to catch his attention

Comment: While this question is on-topic here due to the Haskell involvement, it has a strong type-theoretic bent, so it might have a better chance on [cs.se] (or perhaps even [cstheory.se]). Do not repost; you can request that your question be migrating by flagging it.

Comment: @Gilles Let's see whether it gets any answers and migrate it if not :)

Comment: This seems reminiscent of, although more powerful than, the correspondence between `type Not1 a = a -> Void` and `type Not2 a = forall b . a -> b`.

Comment: Here is a fun question to ponder: for a given type `a`, what is the difference between `forall v. (a -> v) -> v` and `a`? Then observe that `=>` is basically implemented as a function in GHC, and you have discovered a way to represent a value of type `l ~ r` even though that's not an inhabitable type in GHC-Haskell, namely, in its CPS'd form as `forall v. ((l ~ r) => v) -> v`.

Comment: Or, to say it another way, you can read `((l ~ r) => t) -> t` as, "given a term that is well typed assuming that `l ~ r`, return that same term from a context where we have proven `l ~ r` and discharged that assumption".

Comment: @Daniel Wagner, that would be a great answer.

Comment: @DanielWagner - I agree, if you were to write that up as a full answer it'd be really helpful ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm reading it as "given a term which requires `l ~ r`, return that
>   term"

It's "given a term whose type contains `l`, return that term with all `l`s being substituted by `r`s in the type" (or in the other direction `r -> l`). It's a very neat trick, that allows you to delegate all `cong`, `trans`, `subst` and similar stuff to GHC.

Here is an example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, PolyKinds, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, RankNTypes #-}

data Nat = Z | S Nat

data Natty n where
    Zy :: Natty Z
    Sy :: Natty n -> Natty (S n)

data Vec a n where
    Nil  :: Vec a Z
    Cons :: a -> Vec a n -> Vec a (S n)

type family (n :: Nat) :+ (m :: Nat) :: Nat where
    Z     :+ m = m
    (S n) :+ m = S (n :+ m)

assoc :: Natty n -> Natty m -> Natty p -> (((n :+ m) :+ p) ~ (n :+ (m :+ p)) => t) -> t
assoc  Zy     my py t = t
assoc (Sy ny) my py t = assoc ny my py t

coerce :: Natty n -> Natty m -> Natty p -> Vec a ((n :+ m) :+ p) -> Vec a (n :+ (m :+ p))
coerce ny my py xs = assoc ny my py xs
```

**UPDATE**

It's instructive to specialize `assoc`:

```
assoc' :: Natty n -> Natty m -> Natty p ->
            (((n :+ m) :+ p) ~ (n :+ (m :+ p)) => Vec a (n :+ (m :+ p)))
                                               -> Vec a (n :+ (m :+ p))
assoc'  Zy     my py t = t
assoc' (Sy ny) my py t = assoc ny my py t

coerce' :: Natty n -> Natty m -> Natty p -> Vec a ((n :+ m) :+ p) -> Vec a (n :+ (m :+ p))
coerce' ny my py xs = assoc' ny my py xs
```

**Daniel Wagner** explained what's going on in comments:

> Or, to say it another way, you can read ((l ~ r) => t) -> t as, "given
>   a term that is well typed assuming that l ~ r, return that same term
>   from a context where we have proven l ~ r and discharged that
>   assumption".

Let's elaborate the proving part.

In the `assoc'  Zy my py t = t` case `n` is equal to `Zy` and hence we have

```
((Zy :+ m) :+ p) ~ (Zy :+ (m :+ p))
```

which reduces to

```
(m :+ p) ~ (m :+ p)
```

This is clearly identity and hence we can discharge that assumption and return `t`.

At each recursive step we maintain the

```
((n :+ m) :+ p) ~ (n :+ (m :+ p))
```

equation. So when `assoc' (Sy ny) my py t = assoc ny my py t` the equation becomes

```
((Sy n :+ m) :+ p) ~ (Sy n :+ (m :+ p))
```

which reduces to

```
 Sy ((n :+ m) :+ p) ~ Sy (n :+ (m :+ p))
```

due to the definition of `(:+)`. And since constructors are injective

```
constructors_are_injective :: S n ~ S m => Vec a n -> Vec a m
constructors_are_injective xs = xs
```

the equation becomes

```
((n :+ m) :+ p) ~ (n :+ (m :+ p))
```

and we can call `assoc'` recursively.

Finally in the call of `coerce'` these two terms are unified:

```
 1. ((n :+ m) :+ p) ~ (n :+ (m :+ p)) => Vec a (n :+ (m :+ p))
 2.                                      Vec a ((n :+ m) :+ p)
```

Clearly `Vec a ((n :+ m) :+ p)` is `Vec a (n :+ (m :+ p))` under the assumption that `((n :+ m) :+ p) ~ (n :+ (m :+ p))`.

Comment: i think chi's answer gets at "what it means" a bit better, but this is an awesome demonstration of its power. Wow.

Comment: Your example has helped me build a "top-down" intuition about the type's _usage_ (it seems to be a way to safely cast between equivalent types) but I'm still struggling with a "bottom-up" understanding of what it _means_. Do you think you could provide a worked example of how GHC might go about type-checking your `assoc` and `coerce` functions?

Answer (score 4):

> I would have expected an equality proof to have a type more like this:
>
> ```
> Natty x1 → ... → Natty xn → l :~: r
> ```

That's a reasonable alternative. In fact, it's logically equivalent to the one in the Hasochism paper:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, RankNTypes, TypeOperators, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
module Hasochism where

data l :~: r where
  Refl :: l :~: l

type Hasoc l r = forall t. (l ~ r => t) -> t

lemma1 :: forall l r. Hasoc l r -> l :~: r
lemma1 h = h Refl 

lemma2 :: forall l r. l :~: r -> Hasoc l r
lemma2 Refl t = t
```

In a sense, `Hasoc l r` is an impredicative encoding of the constraint `l ~ r`.

The Hasochistic variant is slightly easier to use than the `:~:` one, in that once you have e.g.

```
type family A a
-- ...
proof1 :: Proxy a -> Hasoc a (A a)
proof1 _ = -- ...
```

you can simply use it as in

```
use1 :: forall a. [a] -> [A a]
use1 t = proof1 (Proxy :: Proxy a) t
```

Instead, with

```
proof2 :: Proxy a -> a :~: A a
proof2 _ = -- ...
```

you would need

```
use2 :: forall a. [a] -> [A a]
use2 t = case proof2 (Proxy :: Proxy a) of Refl -> t
```

Comment: Thanks, this confirms my suspicion that the two versions of the proofs are equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

We've had some excellent answers, but as the perpetrator, I thought I'd offer some remarks.

Yes, there are multiple equivalent presentations of these lemmas. The presentation I use is one of them, and the choice is largely a pragmatic one. These days (in a more recent codebase), I go as far as to define

```
-- Holds :: Constraint -> *
type Holds c = forall t . (c => t) -> t
```

This is an example of an *eliminator type*: it abstracts over what it delivers (the *motive* of the elimination) and it requires you to construct zero or more *methods* (one, here) of achieving the motive under more specific circumstances. The way to read it is *backwards*. It says

> If you have a problem (to inhabit any motive type `t`), and nobody else can help, maybe you can make progress by assuming constraint `c` in your method.

Given that the language of constraints admits conjunction (aka tupling), we acquire the means to write lemmas of the form

```
lemma :: forall x1 .. xn. (p1[x1 .. xn],.. pm[x1 .. xn])        -- premises
                       => t1[x1 .. xn] -> .. tl[x1 .. xn]       -- targets
                       -> Holds (c1[x1 .. xn],.. ck[x1 .. xn])  -- conclusions
```

and it might even be that some constraint, a premise `p` or a conclusion `c`, has the form of an equation

```
l[x1 .. xn] ~ r[x1 .. cn]
```

Now, to deploy such a `lemma`, consider the problem of filling a hole

```
_ :: Problem
```

Refine this `_` by the elimination `lemma`, specifying the *targets*. The *motive* comes from the problem at hand. The *method* (singular in the case of `Holds`) remains open.

```
lemma target1 .. targetl $ _
```

and the method hole will not have changed type

```
_ :: Problem
```

but GHC will know a bunch more stuff and thus be more likely to believe your solution.

Sometimes, there's a constraint-versus-data choice to make for what's a (constraint) premise and what's a (data) target. I tend to pick these to avoid ambiguity (Simon likes to guess the `x1 .. xn`, but sometimes needs a hint) and to facilitate *proof by induction*, which is much easier on targets (often the singletons for type level data) than on premises.

As to deployment, for equations, you can certainly switch to a datatype presentation and break out a case analysis

```
case dataLemma target1 .. targetl of Refl -> method
```

and indeed, if you equip yourself with the `Dict` existential

```
data Dict (c :: Constraint) :: * where
  Dict :: c => Dict c
```

you can do a bunch at once

```
case multiLemma blah blah blah of (Refl, Dict, Dict, Refl) -> method
```

but the eliminator form is more compact and readable *when there is at most one method*. Indeed, we can chain multiple lemmas without sliding ever rightward

```
lemma1 ..   $
...
lemmaj ..   $
method
```

If you have such an eliminator with two or more cases, I think it's often better to wrap it up as a GADT, so that usage sites helpfully tag each case with a constructor label.

Anyhow, yes, the point is to choose the presentation of the facts which most compactly enables us to extend the reach of GHC's constraint solving machinery so that more stuff just typechecks. If you're in a scrap with Simon, it's often a good strategy to explain yourself to Dimitrios next door.