# How to read this strange type signature foo :: Sing n -> (KnownNat n => r) -> r

Tags: haskell, syntax

In the singletons package the function [withKnownNat](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.3.1/docs/Data-Singletons-TypeLits.html#v:withKnownNat) has the following strange type signature:

`withKnownNat :: Sing n -> (KnownNat n => r) -> r`.

The `KnownNat n =>` context is not after the `::` (hasType) symbol, but in the second function argument: `-> (KnownNat n => r) ->`.

How do I read this signature? What does it exactly mean? Where is it documented?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should the general type of a “lemma” function be understood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224796/how-should-the-general-type-of-a-lemma-function-be-understood)

Comment: `withKnownNat` takes two arguments; the first is a singleton, and the second is a value of type `r` which is only valid in the context `KnownNat n`. The value `x :: Sing n` is being used to discharge the `KnownNat n` constraint, i.e. to prove that `KnownNat n` is satisfied. Another type that could be assigned to this function is `Sing n -> Dict (KnownNat n)` where `data Dict p where Dict :: p => Dict p`. By pattern matching on a `Dict p`, you bring a constraint `p` into scope; the actual type just removes that middle step of pattern matching on the `Dict`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should the general type of a "lemma" function be understood?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224796/how-should-the-general-type-of-a-lemma-function-be-understood)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between these two signatures:

```
withKnownNat :: Sing n -> (KnownNat n => r) -> r
withKnownNat' :: KnownNat n => Sing n -> r -> r
```

is in who is required to provide evidence that the constraint `KnownNat n` holds.

The hypothetical version with the constraint up front ("after the `::` (hasType) symbol") requires the caller of `withKnownNat'` to be able to prove `KnownNat n` in order to invoke the function. That type signature can be read as something like "if you can prove `KnownNat n`, and give me both a `Sing n` and an `r`, I will give you back an `r`".

That's not particularly useful, as it could be implemented by simply ignoring the `KnownNat n` constraint and the `Sing n` argument and just returning the `r` its given. And without knowing what `r` is it couldn't really do much else to return an `r`; it could possibly do some operations with `n` and raise an error under some conditions, or do some nasty hacking with unsafe functions internally, but that's about it.

In the actual version, it's not the whole `withKnownNat` function that is under the `KnownNat n` constraint, but rather one of its arguments has that constraint. This means the caller of `withKnownNat` *doesn't* have to be able to prove `KnownNat n`; instead the caller can pass an argument that *needs* a proof of `KnownNat n`. As an argument<sup>1</sup> to a function the type `KnownNat n => r` can be read as "a value that is of type `r` *under the assumption* that `KnownNat n` holds". So the whole signature can be read as something like "if you give me both (1) a `Sing n` and (2) a value that is of type `r` under the assumption that `KnownNat n` holds, then I will give you a value of type `r`".

We can see that this is much more useful just from the type. Since it's polymorphic in `r`, the only way `withKnownNat` could get an `r` is from the `KnownNat n => r` we gave it. It can only actually use the `KnownNat n => r` value as a value of type `r` to return to us *if it can prove `KnownNat n`*. So basically this type for `withKnownNat` amounts to a promise that whenever we have a `Sing n`, we can also use anything that needs `KnownNat n` for the same `n`; `withKnownNat` is just what we have to call to convert one into the other.

---

<sup>1</sup> It means the same thing as a return value of a function as well, but it turns out that getting a return value that needs a constraint works out to exactly the same thing as if the whole function needed the constraint, so GHC always converts types like `arg -> (constraints => result)` to just `constraints => args -> result`.

Answer (score 3):

`KnownNat n` is basically just a way of saying “there's a specific number” associated to `n` (it “is” the number `n`). So if you have a constraint `KnownNat n => ...` to anything, it's equivalent to passing in one specific number.

```
withKnownNat' :: Sing n -> (Integer -> r) -> r
```

That in turn is nothing else but a [CPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) way of writing

```
natVal :: Sing n -> Integer
```

...which is essentially a specific instantiation of [the actual](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-2.3.1/docs/Data-Singletons-TypeLits.html#v:natVal)

```
natVal :: KnownNat n => proxy n -> Integer
```

except that the `Sing` has the typeclass constraint baked-in.